# 'MethodImplOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Synchronized'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp

When changing platform for an existing Unity App to UWP (Universal Windows Platform) I get the error

```
error CS0117: 'MethodImplOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Synchronized'
```

How do you fix this?

Unity 2017.2.1f1 with "scripting runtime version" Stable (3.5 eq) and .net scripting backend ".NET" and API compatibility level ".net 4.6"

Comment: I don't know Unity specifics, but UWP is not .NET 4.6. Do you have an option for. NET Standard or something like that?

Comment: I have official tutorials and sample projects which are set-up the same (with 4.6) so it should work?   and also I want 4.6 :D   ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps use a subset of .net, and so do not have access to that class.

I think that you can change the code from, eg this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
protected virtual void GenerateBodyCollider()
    {
```

to this:

```
 private readonly object generateBodyColliderLockObject = new object();
 protected virtual void GenerateBodyCollider()
 {
      lock (generateBodyColliderLockObject)
      {
```